# I keep receiving this error when attempting to run code involving a USB attached microphone on my Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, alsa

I apologize for the length of this question.

I am trying to use Snowboy, a keyword detection program, on my Raspberry Pi, but every time I run the demo with a custom keyword

```
python demo.py dad.pmdl
```

the code pasted below is returned in the terminal.

It seems pretty obvious that this issue lies within ALSA, but I don't know how to find a solution or even approach the problem – I am new to Raspberry Pi, so I am unfamiliar with what ALSA is.

Here is the returned code:

```
"ALSA lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 
'cards.bcm2835.pcm.front.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer             
returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file 
or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM front
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM 
cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 
'cards.bcm2835.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer 
returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file 
or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround21
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 
'cards.bcm2835.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer 
returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file 
or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround21
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 
'cards.bcm2835.pcm.surround40.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer 
returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file 
or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround40
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 
'cards.bcm2835.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer 
returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file 
or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround41
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 
'cards.bcm2835.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer 
returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file 
or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround50
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 
'cards.bcm2835.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer 
returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file 
or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround51
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 
'cards.bcm2835.pcm.surround71.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer 
returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file 
or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround71
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 
'cards.bcm2835.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer 
returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file 
or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM iec958
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 
'cards.bcm2835.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer 
returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file 
or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM spdif
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1286:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 
'cards.bcm2835.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4259:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer 
returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file 
or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM spdif
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM 
cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM 
cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: 
Connection refused

ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: 
Connection refused

Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
Expression 'paInvalidSampleRate' failed in 
'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2048
Expression 'PaAlsaStreamComponent_InitialConfigure( &self->capture, 
inParams, self->primeBuffers, hwParamsCapture, &realSr )' failed in 
'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2719
Expression 'PaAlsaStream_Configure( stream, inputParameters, 
outputParameters, sampleRate, framesPerBuffer, &inputLatency, 
&outputLatency, &hostBufferSizeMode )' failed in 
'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2843
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2demo.py", line 27, in <module>
    detector = snowboydecoder.HotwordDetector(model, sensitivity=0.5)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Snowboy/snowboydecoder.py", line 115, in 
__init__
    stream_callback=audio_callback)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 747, in open
    stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 442, in 
__init__
    self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
IOError: [Errno Invalid sample rate] -9997"
```

Comment: Most of those messages are misleading and harmless. But "Invalid sample rate" means exactly what it says; find out what sample rate Snowboy tries to use, and what is supported by your sound device.

Comment: Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*